# What do I flag this as?

Tags: discussion, flags

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9584224

I am pretty sure that is one to flag. I come across these questions daily, asking homework, or asking for code written for them with a thanks for doing my work at the end.

I've never been sure what to flag them as, so hoping I can/ have been flagging correct.

Comment: Close this one as *Too Broad*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On questions where you have to do all the work and the OP has no clue where to start a *Too Broad* flag will do.

In cases where there is a hint of code or a solution but barely enough to answer use the *Unclear* reason. That one comes with a post notice that has a link to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is full of guidance to improve the post.